# How to calculate the position of the (right circular) cone's vertex projection upon an ellipse?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Starting with a plane parallel to the cone's base (defining a circle with center O), the plane is rotated by φ degrees around one axis that contains the center of the original circle (that is, around a diameter). In the resulting ellipse, how can we calculate this "original center" O, in relation to the ellipse's parameters (center, foci etc) and the angle φ?

Comment: You've seen the Dandelin construction, by any chance?

Comment: I've seen it as I was searching for an answer, although I cannot immediately see how it can be used. If the top  sphere is held constant as the other varies, the ellipse will not contain the O point.